# How do I create a pushdown automata for a language where some characters occur in times in multiples of 2 or 3

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

I have an assignment to create a pushdown automata for $L=\{a^{3n} c^m b^{2n} \mid n,m\geq 0, m\!\mod\! 2=0\}$ and I am confused how to handle $2n$ and $3n$.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out [these hints](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.

Comment: Hint: Build separate automata for $a^{3n}b^{2n}$ and $c^{2k}$ first. Then combine them.

Answer (score 1):

Informally, you are going to use the stack of the automaton to keep track of $n$ and make sure that there really are $2/3$ as many $b$s as $a$s. So every time you see three $a$s in the initial stage you push a token onto the stack, and every time you see two $b$s in the final stage you pop a token from the stack, and then you only accept a word if the stack ends up empty. The states of the automaton can deal with making sure that there are exactly $3n$ $a$s with none left over and likewise $2n$ $b$s and that the $a$s, $b$s and $c$s appear in the right order.

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).

Answer (score 0):

Although the general question is poorly asked, I shall provide some general advice nevertheless, as I think it is educational in general (feel free to comment with "Please consider not to encourage undesirable posting behaviour.", I'm thinking I can contribute. Some bad questions have good answers)

The advice given by Raphael is good and can be generalised: whenever you have a difficult language to construct, try to tackle its separate parts first. (try to *divide and rule*!) If you don't know how to create a PDA for the language $L_1=\{a^{3n} \mid n\geq 0\}$ or $L_2 = \{b^{m} \mid m\!\mod\! 2 = 0\}$, how do you think to create a PDA for $L$?

Remember the general advice (this one applies even for high level research!) (this is a quote, I someone knows from whom please tell me)

> When you're trying to solve a *hard* problem and can't do it, try to find an easier problem you *can't solve* either. Try to solve that one and re-apply this rule in case of failure.

At the very least, this should get you to the essential part that you fail to understand, which means you can ask the right question!

---

Now, a bit more specific: I will not tell you the answer, for this will not help you. As Andrej Bauer has said on this site

> What makes you think that the point of a homework problem is its solution?

But I can provide a way to start. Let's try to solve $L_1$. How can we *count* in a PDA? How can we ensure, that after we can seen an $a$ trice in a row, we remain on a path to an accepting state? Think about this. If you still have doubts, edit you question with your specific problems. This, I think, is the best way to solve such questions. At the very least, what is important here is that *you* solve the question, because I'm not going to make your exam.